# How can I extract a short address from a long address saved in my col1 with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, string, extract, long-integer

How can I extract a short address from a long address saved in my `col1` to `col2`? The problem is I want the name the district and the city

Example for my long address:

```
District ALBERT numero 1234 city CASABLANCA région de NORTH country MOROOCO .
```

I want for my short address just :

```
District ALBERT city CASABLANCA
```

Please I need a help I have many registration in my `col1`, I can't do it manually!

Sorry for my bad English

Comment: Are the address always in the same pattern? `District <something> numero <somenumber> city <somecity> ....`

Comment: yes Jorge . District  and city

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
update yourTable
   set col2 = substring(col1,1,(charindex(col1,'numero')-1)
               + substring(col1,
                           (charindex(col1,'city'),
                           ((charindex(col1,'région')-1)-charindex(col1,'city')))
```

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH Jorge that s work for me . thank you

Answer (score 0):

tested in sql server 2008

```
declare @longAddress varchar(max)
set @longAddress = 'District ALBERT numero 1234 city CASABLANCA région de NORTH country MOROOCO '

--assuming regin follow city
select CHARINDEX('numero',@longAddress)-- this is how you get position of numero and region


--do a substring
select SUBSTRING(@longAddress,1,CHARINDEX('numero',@longAddress)-1) -- get the district
select SUBSTRING(@longAddress,charindex('city',@longAddress),charindex('région',@longAddress)-charindex('city',@longAddress)) -- get the city

--combine
select SUBSTRING(@longAddress,1,CHARINDEX('numero',@longAddress)-1) -- get the district
+SUBSTRING(@longAddress,charindex('city',@longAddress),charindex('région',@longAddress)-charindex('city',@longAddress)) -- get the city
```

Comment: sorry didn't look closed at the results.  I will modify

Comment: thank you so much  chungtinhlakho its work perfectly good solution thank you .